# Visual Studio - lib is not a valid Win32-Application

Tags: c++, visual-studio, makefile, visual-studio-2015, cygwin

I want to run the opensource C++ library "VRPH" on VS 2015 (http://www.coin-or.org/projects/VRPH.xml).

I successfully perfomed the "make" command using cygwin/g++. Doing so leads to some more folders in the VRPH directory.

As described in the install.txt I openend the file VRPH.sln with Visual Studio.

Now VS does the "migration-process" and fires an UpgradeLog.htm with lots of warnings in it (mainly because of the software was created on a 2008 VS-Version), but no errors!

If I now click on "Local-Windows-Debug", the Debug-Window informs about serveral compile processes and the main project "VRPH" creates a VRPH.lib in the Debug-folder.

Having done that the Debugger says: "VRPH.lib is not a valid Win32-Application"

Any idea what to do?

Thank you so much for help!!

Comment: Such message means that you try to execute a library

Comment: ou :-) I feel quite stupid! Thank you so much!

Comment: ooookkk... so what is the actual fix?